# Sybase IQ - BCP error

Tags: sybase, bcp, sap-iq

Trying to copy data from Sybase IQ Table to .txt file using bcp

Command

> C:\Windows\system32>bcp xxTable out \xx\xx\xxTable.txt -S HSPREP_15 -U xxUser -A 16384 -c -t\t$$ -P xxpwd -F  -L   1>\xx\xx\xxTable_rpt.txt

Source Table got about 132 million records
bcp copy about 60 million records to .txt file and then fails with below error:

[image]

There is no issue with disk spare or user credentials.

Any clues? where should i be looking into?

Comment: it seems the file size reaches the upper limit of one file size by bcp tool or windows operating system.

Comment: Check that you're bcping to a NTFS partition which shouldn't have a filesize limit unlike FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

Bcp out doesnt create a file bigger than 2GB which might the case please check

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)